# Server, Auto integration from GitLab

Tags: gitlab, digital-ocean, continuous-deployment

I am the basic for server deployment. Our team creating a project using Node Js and MongoDB. Currently we have using Digital Ocean basic server. Our team is developing the API in local PC and at the same time we also upload the coding to GitLab and clone it to remote server.

The problem is every time, while the changes had done in local, manually I want to clone the entire code to remote server freshly. In this time I remove the old code repo. in remote server and re-clone it for ensuring the new code.

In this time, the running server is down. So, is there any way to handle watch-dog to find any changes in the repo. in GitLab and if the repository is updated, download only the updated and running the server smoothly and non stopping.

Comment: You can use git reset for recover the untouched code, and then, do a git push for download the updates. Even you can do it on a cron if you want to automate it (Probably, there's a lot of better options).

Comment: What are the better options?

Comment: Look into gitlab ci for auto deployment